# 0.8mm PCB for a PSU circuit

Tags: power-supply, safety, pcb-fabrication

I am working on a PSU that converts 230 VAC to 12Vdc (0.1 A). The board has the necessary clearance and creepage distances. Would it cause any safety issue (IEC60950) if the 0.8 mm (or 1.2 mm) thick PCB is used instead of 1.6 mm?

EDIT: There is only one trace under the HV side (highlighted one), the rest is the ground

[image]

Comment: Cannot formally answer this but I wouldn't risk it. If that part of the board is single-sided (no traces on the side opposite to the HV wiring), add that to the question.

Comment: Perhaps ask at engineering.stackexchange.com. It sounds like we're talking about mechanical issues in this question?

Comment: You're probably okay- I see 0.4mm for 'solid insulation' and perhaps as 'functional insulation' this situation does not require even that, but do consult the standard for the final answer. I'd be at least as concerned about the shrink-wrap insulation on the bottoms of those electrolytic capacitors!

Comment: It is not clear to me, if your concern is about the current carrying capacity of the film, high voltage arching, or the safety of the circuit design?